# VPNC cisco + quick mode response rejected error

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, vpnc

I installed a vpnc on my Linux red-hat machine version 6.3

Most of the cases vpnc work well ( connecting to gateway customers by vpnc )

But against some particular customers ( Cisco gateways ) ,  immediately after I activate the vpnc I get the following messages:

```
    vpnc: quick mode response rejected:  (ISAKMP_N_INVALID_PAYLOAD_TYPE)(1)
```

In this case Vpnc could not be connected

Please advice what the problem here?

```
     [root@TEST-LINUX-MACHINE /var/tmp]# vpnc
```

.

```
       Enter password for user@216.134.162.39: 


Connect Banner:
| Remote access to UGG company resources is restricted to AUTHORIZED USERS!
| 
| Company resources may only be used for the purpose of performing work-related duties.
| The user is responsible for protecting the confidentiality and integrity of the      company resources.
| Violation may cause disciplinary action.
| By clicking on "Continue" the user agrees with the rules above.
|
```

.

```
 RTNETLINK answers: File exists
 **vpnc: quick mode response rejected:  (ISAKMP_N_INVALID_PAYLOAD_TYPE)(1)**
 this means the concentrator did not like what we had to offer.
```

.

```
 Possible reasons are:

 * concentrator configured to require a firewall
   this locks out even Cisco clients on any platform expect windows
   which is an obvious security improvment. There is no workaround (yet).
```

.

```
* concentrator configured to require IP compression
   this is not yet supported by vpnc.
   Note: the Cisco Concentrator Documentation recommends against using
   compression, expect on low-bandwith (read: ISDN) links, because it
   uses much CPU-resources on the concentrator
```

I also try to do the follwoing

```
  Add the line "NAT Traversal Mode cisco-udp" in /etc/vpnc.conf
```

Or

```
   Add the line "Local Port 10000" in /etc/vpnc.conf
```

But they dosent help and I still get the bad messages ( chuld not be connected by the vpnc )

Please advice where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with the vpnc version of CentOS 7. Using a newer vpnc version with the latest changes from SVN has solved it.

The easiest way for Red Hat or CentOS is using the [Fedora 24 source package](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/24/Workstation/source/tree/Packages/v/) and compiling it. Under CentOS 7, the following should work:

```
$ sudo yum install gcc make redhat-rpm-config libgcrypt-devel libgpg-error-devel gnutls-devel
$ mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
$ test -f ~/.rpmmacros || echo '%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild' > ~/.rpmmacros
$ curl -LO https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/24/Workstation/source/tree/Packages/v/vpnc-0.5.3-27.svn550.fc24.src.rpm
$ rpmbuild --rebuild vpnc-0.5.3-27.svn550.fc24.src.rpm
$ sudo yum localinstall ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/vpnc-0.5.3-27.svn550.el7.local.x86_64.rpm
```